# JavaScript file is not loaded when called in <script> tag from html

Tags: javascript, node.js, script-tag, node-serialport

I am quite new to this and I don't understand why my script is not loaded from html... This is my main problem.

Than, I would like to get list of available COM ports and send something to available port. I installed serialport v 6.1.1. I created index.html with  tags but does not seems to be working(loading). When this is working I would like to get form on html to get and pass data (input text) to received.js. There might be errors within js files but can't tell because none of scripts is loaded.

Console is returning error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'    [Learn More] index.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'    [Learn More] received.js:1
```

Starting point is server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var http_IP='127.0.0.1';
var http_port = 9876;

//generate html
function onRequest(request, responce){
  responce.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function(error, data){
   if(error){
      responce.writeHead(404);
      responce.write('File not found');
   }else{
     responce.write(data);
   }
    responce.end();
 });

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(http_port);
console.log('listening on http://' + http_IP + ':' + http_port);
```

index.js (nor alert or console is printing message)

```
console.log("Hello");
alert('Hello');

var serialport = require('serialport');

// list serial ports:
serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);

  });
});

serialport.list((err, ports) => {
  console.log('ports', ports);
  if (err) {
    document.getElementById('error').textContent = err.message
    return
  } else {
    //var port = new serialport('"FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+FT9PQV36A\0000"', { baudRate: 115200})
    document.getElementById('error').textContent = message
  }

  if (ports.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('error').textContent = 'No ports discovered'
  }

  const headers = Object.keys(ports[0])
  const table = createTable(headers)
  tableHTML = ''
  table.on('data', data => tableHTML += data)
  table.on('end', () => document.getElementById('ports').innerHTML = tableHTML)
  ports.forEach(port => table.write(port))
  table.end();

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></>
  <meta http-equiv="X_UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" ></>
  <title>My Serial Port v1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3 id="h3">Serial Port v1</h3>

  <FORM class="form" NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="POST" onsubmit="return false">Enter command to process (without "()"): <BR>
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" id ="inputbox" VALUE="">
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" id = "send_button" Value="Click" onClick="">
  </FORM>

  <script type"text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>   

    <script src="received.js">
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

received.js

```
const serialport = require('serialport');

var ready ='';


const portName = 'COM20';
var port = new serialport(portName, { parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\r\n'), baudRate: 19200});


//**** SENDING

port.open(function(err){
  if(err){
    return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
  }


  var button = document.getElementById('send_button');
  var form = document.getElementsByName('myform');
  console.log("")

  // var value= '';

  // handling html form
  button.onclick = function myFormHandler(){

    var value = button.form.inputbox.value;

    console.log('Entered value: ', value);
    // storing entered value
    localStorage.setItem('command_value', value);
    command_optics = value;
    console.log('Value of value', value);
    console.log('Value of command_optics', command_optics);
    // recalling entered value
    var command_optics =  localStorage.getItem('command_value');
    console.log('command_optics: ', command_optics);
    // clearing local storage from previous input
    localStorage.clear()
    //  sending command inputted into form textbox
    var sent_data = '(' + command_optics.toUpperCase() + ')\r\n';
    var received_raw_data;

// sending data over COM port
      port.write(sent_data, function(err){
        if(err){
          return console.log('Error on write', err.message);
        }
        console.log('Port.write: ', sent_data);
      }
    );
  }

  //****RECEIVING

// receiving data from COM port
  port.on('data', function(data){

    // raw data passed to var received_raw_data for displaying in html
    received_raw_data = data;

    //trim 'C:', 'R:', 'L:' from string
    // data = data.replace('CRL:','')
    if(data.length > 50){
        data = data.slice(2);
    }

    console.log('Data received (raw): ', data);
    // document.getElementById('data_from_optics').textContent = data
    // writing data from optics module into html
    document.getElementById('data_from_optics').textContent = received_raw_data;
  });

  // Read data that is available but keep the stream from entering "flowing mode"
  port.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Data2:', port.read());
  });

});
```

Comment: You cannot run `server.js` in a browser, you need a **node.js environment**. Run `node server.js` in the terminal for example. The rest of the code seems ok to me.

Comment: tldr; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Like @Quentin has explained your always returning the same website resource, you never return any Javascript from you server.js.  What you need to do is implement some sort of routing logic, this can be tricky and is the reason why most people use a lib that does this all for you.  eg. Express or KOA.. etc.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović I am running server.js from cmd unless you meant something different.

Comment: who ever downvoted can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your HTTP server:

> ```
> function onRequest(request, responce){
>   responce.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
>   fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function(error, data){
>    if(error){
>       responce.writeHead(404);
>       responce.write('File not found');
>    }else{
>      responce.write(data);
>    }
>     responce.end();
>  });
>
> }
> ```

So…

1. The browser asks for `index.js`
2. The server says "OK! Here is some HTML"
3. The server outputs the contents of `index.html`

You need to pay attention to which file the browser is asking for, and give them that instead of *always* sending `index.html`.

Since you are sending the browser HTML instead of JavaScript, it throws an error when it sees `<` at the start of the HTML and tries to treat it as JavaScript.

---

Then look at `index.js`…

> ```
> alert('Hello');
>
> var serialport = require('serialport');
> ```

`alert` is a browser function so will run fine if you ever execute it in the browser.

But requiring the serialport library? That won't run in the browser. It depends on Node.

Comment: So if i send ./ndex.js instead of /index.html I get rid of `<` problem but now i am getting plain text of index.js rather than "processed" javascript file. Can it be odne without express as sugested by  @Keith ?

Comment: @cheeroke — Write it as a function. Call the function. Send the output. (But that probably won't make much sense the response to a `<script src>`).